# Problem with Laravel queued Jobs. Strange behavior different for dev and production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-artisan

I have a strange behavior when a Job runs:
On dev server (win 7 php 7.2.10) everything work fine,
on the production server Linux centOS php 7.0.10 it throws an Exception:

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously timed out.
```

config/queue.php

```
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

this happens after a job is queued ... when it starts working ... after about 30 seconds (Failed)
the exception is in the failed_jobs table

I though it could be dependent by the php max_execution_time directive but when i do

```
php -r "echo ini_get('max_execution_time') . PHP_EOL;"
```

it shows me zero (no timeout ... which is correct)

the Job is queued in this way:

```
dispatch((new Syncronize($file))->onQueue('sync'));
```

The Sincronize Job has no timeout (has 1 try) and simply calls two artisan commands which work perfecly both on prod and on dev server if called from the shell.

https://pastebin.com/mnaHWq71

to start jobs on the dev server I use

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=sync,newsletter,default
```

on prod server I use this

https://pastebin.com/h7uv5gca

any idea of what can be the cause ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Laravel 5.7 requires php >= 7.1.3. Also, do you specify the `--timeout` option from the command line?

Comment: 5.4 ... no --timeout specified shuld be zero (no timeout) by default

Comment: How long does the job run for? The default `--timeout` setting is 60 seconds. Also, what's your `retry_after` setting?

Comment: job can run for several minutes .. it syncronizes an entire set of 30000 products .. no retry_after set

Comment: There has to be a `retry_after`. Check `config/queue.php` under the connection you use. If it's shorter than the job takes to run, it might be retried causing a failure. Also, try adding a `--timeout=600` or some higher number to your worker process (making sure the `retry_after` is higher than the timeout)

Comment: retry_after is refering to the failed job time not the started one. added my config/queue.php to the question

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem ... 
was in my service /etc/init.d/myservice

```
cd /var/www/html/
case "$1" in
start)
    php artisan queue:work --queue=sync,newsletter,default &
    echo $!>/var/run/myservice.pid
    echo "server daemon started"
;;
```

I didn't check if the process was already running so I launch it twice.
I saw 2 processes in `ps axu` and seems that this was the cause
This check solved

```
if [ -e /var/run/myservice.pid ]; then
   echo "Service is running. Call stop first".
   exit 1
fi
```